# android - controlling state of RadioButton

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button

i am gettin 1 problem in d android application that i have made.

-> i have a 3 RadioButton's on 1 activity screen

-> after a Button is pressed(on same activity) the text associated with all of them should change and all RadioButton's must be unchecked and should be clickable

the text is changing properly and the RadioButton's are becoming unchecked but the problem am facing is that:

1. if suppose RadioButton 1 is selected and then after pressing the Button am unable to click that same RadioButton until i click some other RadioButton.

Why so??

Comment: Could you post some code for us to have a look at?

Answer (score 2):

the solution is for future readers

create RadioGroup instance in .java file and call instance.clearCheck()

Answer (score 2):

Do not use RadioButton.setChecked method directly.
Use RadioGroup.check method to check RadioButton programmabaly

```
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myFavouriteGroup);
int selectedItem = 0; // the fist item in rgGroup must be selected
.... do something ....
if (selectedItem >= 0)
{
   rg.check(rg.getChildAt(selectedItem).getId());
}
....
```

After this user can change selected item to another.

Answer (score 1):

Part1

```
RadioButton option1  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
option1.setText(temp.substring(answerCount[0]+1, answerCount[1]));

if(option1.isChecked())
{
    score+=1;
}
```

Part2

```
option1.setChecked(false);
option1.setClickable(true);
option1.setText(temp.substring(answerCount[aCount]+1, answerCount[aCount+1]));
```

Part 1 is executed Ist and then Part 2 is a part of 1 of my methods..
is that enough??

Comment: Why not just edit the original question to include this code?

Comment: no i have found out the error..

in my .java i had instances of all radiobuttons but not of radiogroup.

once i made RadioGroup instance i called clearCheck() to get rid off the problem..

anyways thank you for your kind help